# Why don’t the baptisms in Acts use the trinitarian formula?

Tags: trinity, baptism, acts, jesus-name-baptism

At the end of the book of Matthew, we see Jesus’ command for baptism in the name of all three persons of the trinity:

> “Therefore go and make disciples of all nations, baptizing them in the name of the Father and of the Son and of the Holy Spirit,”
> ‭‭Matthew‬ ‭28:19‬ ‭

However, in the book of Acts, there are many instances where baptisms only occur in the name of Jesus:

- Acts 2:28 – be baptized…in the name of Jesus Christ.
- Acts 8:16 – baptized in the name of the Lord Jesus.
- Acts 10:48 – baptized in the name of the Lord.
- Acts 19:5 – baptized in the name of the Lord Jesus.

So why the lack of the three persons baptism as explicitly stated by Jesus in Matthew?

Comment: @curiousdannii it is a duplicate yeah, but the question only has one answer that isn’t too detailed imo

Comment: @ellied Then I believe the right path is to update the question (if relevant) and or put a bounty on it.

Comment: not sure who closed the question… the other question references a catholic perspective with sacraments. this one clearly doesn’t…

Comment: I'm guessing it's because the other question scopes it to Trinitarianism, not Catholicism specifically. A given answer might be from a Catholic perspective, but that doesn't limit the question itself.